# Apply a condition to multiple columns to replace the

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with the below columns, some of the IGFRESAS columns have data in them, but I'll only be replacing the data that doesn't exist based on these conditions - see print screen
[image]
I want to use the condition EV_EM == 0  then copy EV_RND to all the IGFREAS4X columns.

I got this to work for one column:

```
df["IGFREAS41"]=np.where(df['EV_EM'] == 0, df['EV_RND'], df["IGFREAS41"])
```

I tried this:
columns = ["IGFREAS41", "IGFREAS43", "IGFREAS44", "IGFREAS42"]
np.where(df['EV_EM'] == 0, df['EV_RND'], df[columns])

I got this error:
---> 13 np.where(df['EV_EM'] == 0, df['EV_RND'], df[columns])

File <**array_function** internals>:180, in where(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13,) (13,) (13,4)

Comment: What's the desired output here? Screenshots aren't very useful for people wanting to run and attempt a solution with your code. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples as to how to provide data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly the problem then the following works:

```
import pandas as pd

data={"EV_EM":[0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1],
      "EV_RND":["EM Not Avaiable","","EM Not Avaiable1","EM Not Avaiable2","","EM Not Avaiable3","EM Not Avaiable4","",""],
      "IGFREAS41":["","","","","","","","",""],
      "IGFREAS42":["","","","","","","","",""],
      "IGFREAS43":["","","","","","","","",""],
      }
df=pd.DataFrame(data)


mask=df["EV_EM"]==0

cols_to_fill=[x for x in df.columns if x.startswith("IGFREAS")]

df.loc[mask,cols_to_fill]=df["EV_RND"]
```